# Using Laravel Passport with iOS (Swift)

Tags: php, ios, swift, laravel-5

I am trying login in Swift (iOS) via based Laravel webservice. At Laravel side I am using [passaport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#installation). When I tried login with postman, it is works. However I couldn't for Swift. Swift side like this:

```
    @IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
    let url = "http://mytest:8000/oauth/token"
    let myUrl = URL(string:url)

    let params = [
        "grant_type":"password",
        "client_id": "1",
        "client_secret": "W04TCZ55lIrDjaT71LOUTY0ABT1why0fyPpK8EtY",
        "username": email.text!,
        "password": password.text!,
        "scope":"*"]

    Alamofire.request(myUrl!, method: .post, parameters: params).validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result{
        case .success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            print(json)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

succesful case is works but response of json =

```
{
 "message" : "The user credentials were incorrect.",
 "error" : "invalid_credentials"
}
```

Finally I can't login from iOS side. I want to use Laravel backend for Swift app. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

What I see missing here is `encoding` parameter which should be set to `JSONEncoding.default` as you are using `application/json` content type. `Alamofire.request()` sets `URLEncoding.default` as its default encoding, so your back-end probably can't parse the call properly.

therefore:

```
Alamofire.request(myUrl!, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).responseJSON { (response) in
   ...
}
```

Comment: I added encoding but doesn't change anything

Comment: Then it's hard to say what goes wrong. Check your parameters carefully, maybe a typo in client secret or a leading/trailing space in the email or password, etc.